# Draggable without jQuery UI object by Id error

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I am trying to make a div draggable using jQuery, but without jQuery UI, I can't figure out why I get an error if when I use the e.target.id, the value in this field at some point is empty or null.

If I hard code the Id in the function it works pretty well, what am I missing here?

I appreciate your help.

This is my code:

```
 <div id="Div1" style="width: 100px; background-color: red">test</div>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        dragObject.init("Div1");
    });
```

**jQdrag.js**

```
var dragObject = (function () {

    var init = function (dragObj) {
        addListeners(dragObj);
    };

    var addListeners = function (dragObj) {

        document.getElementById(dragObj).addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    };

    mouseDown = function (e) {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
    };

    mouseUp = function () {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
    };

    divMove = function (e) {
      debugger
        //var div = document.getElementById("Div1");
      var div = document.getElementById(e.target.id); //ERROR

        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        div.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    };

    return {

        init: function (dragObj)
        {
            init(dragObj);
        }

    };
})();
```

Comment: If you keep the cursor over the div, it works fine. But if you move the mouse too quickly and leave the div, `e.target` is the window, not  the div.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but how can I prevent this?
Or how can I check if the object in e.target is still the object I need to be draggable?
Thanks again.